# Show data values in PHPExcel chart (i.e. on top of bars etc.)

Tags: php, excel, charts, phpexcel

I'm working with PHPExcel Version 1.8 (https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

I mainly use it to create charts. Everything is working fine, but I can't get PHPExcel to create charts with the data values displayed inside the chart. I'm generating XLSX-files using the "Excel 2007" writer of PHPExcel.

Upper image: That's how it looks right now, lower image: That's what I want to achieve...

[image]

I would really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem: Just add a layout to the plot area, which has set showVal = true:

```
// Set layout
$layout = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();
$layout->setShowVal(true);

//  Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout, $series);

...
```

I hope this might safe someone else some time! :-)